# React native / expo app: how to make a diagonal background?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm building an availability calendar in our app and for days that have check-ins and check-outs (which happen at 12:00PM) I wish to show the calendar day either half green or half right, like this:

[image: calendar]

With CSS, currently, we achieve this effect like this:

`linear-gradient(to bottom right, #beffbe 50%, #ffbdc2 51%)`

What would be the best way of implementing this?

I'm using expo so maybe something involving `<LinearGradient>` ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is the best solution, but you can achieve this effect by adding a bordered `<View />` as a sibling of your content:

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

render() {
(...)

  <View style={{
    borderRightWidth: width,
    borderRightColor: 'red',
    borderTopWidth: width,
    borderTopColor: 'green',
    position: 'absolute',
    opacity: 0.5
  }} />

[Your content goes here]

(...)
}
```

Hope it helps